# Prove that $\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}dx$

I've seen many post about $\int\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}dx$ but I don't know
how to proceed with this one, with just real methods. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\sim\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ for $x\to\pm\infty$. Or even $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}<\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ for $|x|>1$.

Comment: @Jean - Claude Arbaut why $|x|\gt 1$? Doesn't the inequality holds for all$x$?

Comment: @NimuBasak Correct. I had the integral in mind: you don't want to integrate $1/x^2$ near $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since the integrand is even
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx
 = 2 \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx
$$
and
$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx 
 < \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4}}dx
 = \int_1^{\infty}x^{-2}dx
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Okay. I think that I got it, but, whats happens with $\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}dx$  ?

Comment: Oh, I can see it like a constant, right?

Comment: @ManuelVargas correct :) it is a bounded function on a bounded interval

Comment: Can I say that if an integral converges, any multiple of it converges too?

Comment: @ManuelVargas yes, as long as it is a *finite* multiple...

Answer (score 4):

For all $x$,

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\le\min\left(1,\frac1{x^2}\right).$$

You can integrate the $RHS$ explicitly (though it is obvious that this converges).

[image]

Comment: What software can you use to produce plots like that?

Comment: @gt6989b: Microsoft Mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful too!